# understanding cross-reference in reference counting method of garbage collection

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, reference-counting, cross-reference

While reading a book I came to know that implementations of JavaScript tend to use one of the two garbage collection methods. Either it is mark-and-sweep, or reference counting. I understand the concept of reference counting. It is counted that how many references of a value exists. When a variable is assigned a value, reference counting for that variable increases by 1 and when variables are overridden by some other value, reference counting of 'THIS' value decreases by 1. The process continues and when number of references reaches to 0, the value is considered safe for deletion.

Then there was a section explaining the cross-reference problem with reference-counting method in garbage collection. It says, whenever a property of object A is assigned the reference to object B and vice-versa, then the cross-reference problem arrives because the counting never reaches to zero. The example given in the book was something like this

```
var A = new Object();
var B = new Object();
A.prop = B;
B.prop = A;
```

I completely missed this. I mean, how the above code results in a cross-reference problem? Why the counting never reaches zero.

**Note** I wrote everything I understood about reference counting. If I am wrong somewhere, pleas tell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example:

```
class Person{
    string name;
    Person lover;
}

A = new Person("A");
B = new Person("B");
A.lover = B;
B.lover = A;

A = NULL;
B = NULL;
```

[image: explain]

So, the counting never reaches zero.